# How to list data from MYSQL in HTML

Tags: html, css, mysql, go, templates

I want to list the data registered in my table over mysql database on html using Go. How can I achieve this. I am able to list on the terminal console, but unfortunately I could not do it with html.

[image: example]

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func add_user(isimsoyisim string, telefon string, eposta string) bool {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:PASSWORD@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/deneme1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    add, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO telefondefter (isimsoyisim,telefon,eposta) VALUES (?,?,?)", (isimsoyisim), (telefon), (eposta))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(add)
    defer db.Close()
    return true
}

func kayitekle1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var tmplt = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("html/index.html"))
    tmplt.Execute(w, nil)
}

func kayitekle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    var isimsoyisim = r.Form["isimsoyisim"]
    var telefon = r.Form["telefon"]
    var eposta = r.Form["eposta"]
    fmt.Println(isimsoyisim, telefon, eposta)
    if add_user(isimsoyisim[0], telefon[0], eposta[0]) {
        var tmplt = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("html/index3.html"))
        tmplt.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        var tmplt = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("html/error.html"))
        tmplt.Execute(w, nil)
    }
}

func kayitlist(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var tmplt = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("html/index2.html"))
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM telefondefter")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        panic(err)
        return
    }
    var id int
    var isimsoyisim string
    var telefon string
    var eposta string
    var ps []PersonData

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&id, &isimsoyisim, &telefon, &eposta)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            panic(err)
            return
        }
        ps = append(ps, PersonData{id: id, isimsoyisim: isimsoyisim, telefon: telefon, eposta: eposta})
    }
    tmplt.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/scss/", http.StripPrefix("/scss/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("scss"))))
    http.Handle("/src/", http.StripPrefix("/src/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("src"))))
    http.Handle("/rtl/", http.StripPrefix("/rtl/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("rtl"))))
    http.Handle("/html/", http.StripPrefix("/html/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("html"))))
    http.Handle("/layouts/", http.StripPrefix("/layouts/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("layouts"))))
    http.Handle("/tmp/", http.StripPrefix("/tmp/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("tmp"))))

    fmt.Println("Server Başlatılıyor")

    http.HandleFunc("/", kayitekle1)
    http.HandleFunc("/kayitekle", kayitekle)
    http.HandleFunc("/kayitlist", kayitlist)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8999", nil)

}
```

HTML (INDEX2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Golang Defter Uygulaması </title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../src/assets/img/favicon.ico"/>
    <link href="../layouts/modern-light-menu/css/light/loader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../layouts/modern-light-menu/css/dark/loader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../layouts/modern-light-menu/loader.js"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../layouts/modern-light-menu/css/light/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../layouts/modern-light-menu/css/dark/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->

    <!--  BEGIN CUSTOM STYLE FILE  -->
    <link href="../src/assets/css/light/scrollspyNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../src/assets/css/dark/scrollspyNav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--  END CUSTOM STYLE FILE  -->
</head>
<body class="layout-boxed" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navSection" data-bs-offset="100">

    <!-- BEGIN LOADER -->
    <div id="load_screen"> <div class="loader"> <div class="loader-content">
        <div class="spinner-grow align-self-center"></div>
    </div></div></div>
    <!--  END LOADER -->

    <!--  BEGIN NAVBAR  -->

    <!--  END NAVBAR  -->

    <!--  BEGIN MAIN CONTAINER  -->
    <div class="main-container " id="container">

        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="cs-overlay"></div>
        <div class="search-overlay"></div>

        <!--  BEGIN SIDEBAR  -->
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper sidebar-theme">

              <nav id="sidebar">

                <div class="navbar-nav theme-brand flex-row  text-center">
                    <div class="nav-logo">
                        <div class="nav-item theme-logo">
                            <a href="./index.html">
                                <img src="../src/assets/img/logo.svg" class="navbar-logo" alt="logo">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-item theme-text">
                            <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link"> ERMAT </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav-item sidebar-toggle">
                        <div class="btn-toggle sidebarCollapse">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevrons-left"><polyline points="11 17 6 12 11 7"></polyline><polyline points="18 17 13 12 18 7"></polyline></svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="shadow-bottom"></div>
                <ul class="list-unstyled menu-categories" id="accordionExample">
                    <li class="menu active">

                            <div>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right"><polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline></svg>
                            </div>

                        <ul class="collapse submenu list-unstyled show" id="dashboard" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="./index.html"> Kayıt Ekleme </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="./index2.html"> Kayıtları Listele </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>

        </div>
        <!--  END SIDEBAR  -->

        <!--  BEGIN CONTENT AREA  -->
        <div id="content" class="main-content">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="container">

                    <!-- BREADCRUMB -->

                    <!-- /BREADCRUMB -->


                    <div class="row layout-top-spacing">

                        <div id="basic" class="col-lg-12 layout-spacing">
                            <div class="statbox widget box box-shadow">
                                <div class="widget-header">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <h4>Telefon Defter Kayit Listesi</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="widget-content widget-content-area">

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 ">
                                            <form name="kayitekle" action="/kayitekle" method="post">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ermat Kayit List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<center><p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">AdSoyad</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefon</th>
      <th scope="col">Eposta</th>


  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{.id}}</td>
      <td>{{.isimsoyisim}}</td>
      <td>{{.telefon}}</td>
      <td>{{.eposta}}</td>
    <tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
  </p></center>
<!-- partial -->

</body>
</html>




                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

            <!--  BEGIN FOOTER  -->
            <div class="footer-wrapper">
                <div class="footer-section f-section-1">
                    <p class="">Copyright © <span class="dynamic-year">2022</span> <a target="_blank" href="https://designreset.com/cork-admin/">Ermat</a>, All rights reserved.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-section f-section-2">
                    <p class="">Coded with Deniz Korkmazer<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-heart"><path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0-7.78z"></path></svg></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--  END FOOTER  -->

        </div>
        <!--  END CONTENT AREA  -->
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN CONTAINER -->

    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="../src/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/src/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/src/mousetrap/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/src/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../layouts/modern-light-menu/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/plugins/src/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="../src/assets/js/scrollspyNav.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```